# Killing a python server through shell interrupt

Tags: python, bash, shell, simplehttpserver

I have a bash script that runs a few python scripts in the background. I've attached an interrupt signal to them, so that when I ctrl-c, I escape from all of them. However, my python script starts a SimpleHTTPServer. The interrupt will kill the python script, but will not kill the SimpleHTTPServer. How would I go about ending that process as well?

I have the following shell in `main-script.sh`:

```
trap 'kill %1; kill %2' SIGINT
cd "$DIR_1" && ./script1.py &
cd "$DIR_2" && ./script2.py &
./script3.py
```

The python scripts just start up a SimpleHTTPServer with a few extra headers.

Running a `ps x` in the terminal gives

```
60958 pts/1    S      0:00 /bin/bash ./main-script.sh
60959 pts/1    S      0:00 /bin/bash ./main-script.sh
60960 pts/1    S      0:02 /usr/bin/python ./script1.py host:port1
60962 pts/1    S      0:01 /usr/bin/python ./script2.py host:port2
```

And after a ctrl-c

```
60960 pts/1    S      0:02 /usr/bin/python ./script1.py host:port1
60962 pts/1    S      0:01 /usr/bin/python ./script2.py host:port2
```

Edit here is the main code that starts the server:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import SimpleHTTPServer
import sys
from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
import BaseHTTPServer

def test(HandlerClass=SimpleHTTPRequestHandler,
         ServerClass=BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer):

    protocol = "HTTP/1.0"

    server_address = (host, port)
    HandlerClass.protocol_version = protocol
    httpd = ServerClass(server_address, HandlerClass)
    httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: include code which starts server, it depends on it

Comment: @ArtemBernatskyi Added the code snip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually not entirely sure this works since I'm on windows and can't verify this now. But your python instance should be the one recieving the Ctrl-C signal (or SIGINT as it's called).

There for this piece of code should work in Python:

```
import signal
from sys import exit
from os import remove

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    try:
        ## == Try to close any sockets etc nicely:
        ##    s in this case is an example of socket().
        ##    Whatever you got, put the exit stuff here.
        s.close() 
    except:
        pass
    ## == If you have a pid file:
    remove(pidfile)
    exit(1)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

## == the rest of your code goes here
```

This should catch `SIGINT` and stop nicely.
And if all else fails, just pure shutdown happens.

Comment: @JoeFromAccounting Joe, from accounting, you're welcome. Thank you for bumping up my salary. All the best //The janitor.